# Prevent enterprise iPad kiosks from asking for Apple ID password?

Tags: ipad, apple-id

We have a fleet of iPad kiosks out at our branch locations and all of them ask periodically for the Apple ID password / iCloud password. This is not connected to any app. It's like the system itself asking. End-users do not and will never have that password. Is there a way to prevent this for enterprise fleets?

Comment: Are they configured manually or managed using a MDM (Mobile Device Management) system?

Comment: We use an MDM. Words